# What are the best Android Apps for homebrewing

Tags: recipe-formulation, beer-tools

I have noticed there are a bunch of homebrewing tools/apps available in the android store. I'm wondering what the best ones are. Some of them you have to pay for, i'm okay with paying for an app if it's useful.

Features i'm looking for are recipe formulation, brew day log and timers...

Thanks

Comment: I don't know of any that have flipped my skirt. I am an Android developer, and I just started writing one. I am looking for peoples opinions and ideas so I can build the right thing. I don't want to compete with BeerSmith, rather be compatible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For BJCP Info, I use [BJCP 2015](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ru.orangesoftware.bjcp2015)

Beersmith ([lite](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=beersmithllc.beersmith.beersmith2) or [full](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.beersmith.beersmith2full)) is a good tool (but I tend to do everything on the PC, so I do not use the app that much). The app allows for recipe formulation, logs and timers.

[Brew Timer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.brewtimer) is a life saver for letting you know when to do what. Easy to configure. The pre-warning function is one of the best features.

Lastly, [CvPad](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cvpad.mobile.android.wt.unit), for all your conversion needs.

Answer (score 1):

On my phone the only 3 beer-related apps I have installed are:

[Jomebrew Beer Stats and Conversions](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=appinventor.ai_aielloster.BeerCalc&hl=en)

I grabbed this primarily to convert Brix to SG because my refractometer is in Brix. The interface isn't great, but its a quick simple app for doing some basic conversions. It will also take OG and SG and give you ABV and attenuation. It also does have a timer sections to it where you can set up a few timers for a step mash or boil additions.

[Brewer's Friend](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.brewersfriend.free&hl=en)

I use their website for creating and storing recipes, so grabbed their app too. It is fairly new and has some bugs, but isn't bad for tweaking a recipe here or there, or if I'm out talking to other brewers and someone wants to know what I used in a beer I can look it up.

I think this app also has a brew-day section where it guides you through the recipe and each step, letting you track measurements along the way, but I never use it.

[BJCP Droid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.transmutex.bjcpdroid&hl=en)

Which I mostly just use when tasting or researching, for style guide info.

---

I'm also a computer programmer and like my share of gadgets, but for me, I like just having a good old fashioned printout of my recipe and a spiral notebook to track my readings, measurements, and tasting notes for each batch.

The only thing I do on my phone on brew day is the brix->SG conversions and timers.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'll be sure to check these apps out.